# Python request handler not concatenating strings sometimes

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have a request handler that gets a person's signature from a POST request, saves it to Google cloud storage, and then sends a link to the signature in an HTML email.

```
def handler(request):
    pic = request.POST.get('signature')
    firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
    lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
    data = pic[22:]
    png_image = base64.b64decode(data)
    link = firstname+'/'+lastname+'/'+"sig.png"  #create storage URI
    temp_location = '/tmp/myfile.png'
    with open(temp_location,'wb') as f:
        f.write(png_image)

    client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(os.path.abspath('evmailkeys.json'))
    bucket = client.get_bucket('mybucket')
    blob = bucket.blob(link)
    blob.upload_from_filename(temp_location)

    signature = "https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/" + link  
    subject = 'signature'
    sender = 'email@email.com'
    message = f"""<div>Signature: <img src={signature} /></div>"""  
    recipients = ["recipient1@email.com"]

    send_mail(subject, "hello", sender, recipients, html_message=message)
```

This works about half of the time, but the other half of the time, the link to `signature` only contains `firstname`, so it doesn't work. Meaning, instead of `signature` being `https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/john/galt/sig.png` it only sends as `https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/john`. The signature image saves to the right place in cloud storage and exists where it should, but something happens to the `link` string. Again, this happens about half the time, but the other half of the time it works as intended. Why would that be?

Comment: I don't see how link could ever be just `https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/john`, because your code explicitly puts `sig.png` on the end.

Comment: Agreed. And the photo does save to `/mybucket/john/galt/sig.png`.  It's there. But the link shows up in the email as `mybucket/john`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was whitespace. If someone entered their name as "John " instead of "John", then it broke the link creation. My solution is to remove the whitespace from all names when creating a Google Cloud Storage URI.

```
def handler(request):
    pic = request.POST.get('signature')
    firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
    lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
    data = pic[22:]
    png_image = base64.b64decode(data)

    firstname_nowhitespace = firstname.replace(" ", "")
    lastname_nowhitespace = lastname.replace(" ", "")

    link = firstname_nowhitespace + '/' +lastname_nowhitespace + '/' + "sig.png"  #create storage URI
    temp_location = '/tmp/myfile.png'
    with open(temp_location,'wb') as f:
        f.write(png_image)

    client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(os.path.abspath('evmailkeys.json'))
    bucket = client.get_bucket('mybucket')
    blob = bucket.blob(link)
    blob.upload_from_filename(temp_location)

    signature = "https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/" + link  
    subject = 'signature'
    sender = 'email@email.com'
    message = f"""<div>Signature: <img src={signature} /></div>"""  
    recipients = ["recipient1@email.com"]

    send_mail(subject, "hello", sender, recipients, html_message=message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh and You can always use,

```
firstname = request.POST.get('firstname').strip()
```

Which is recommended and widely used for these kind of inputs :)

If you want to Remove all white spaces

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

slugify(firstname)
```

is one of the clean things that can be used for url building. "Some Name" will be "some-name"

Comment: `.strip()` doesn't work for this because some people's names have a space in the middle, like Jean Pierre or something. That's why I had to use `.replace()`